# Adding Numbers to a Series of Numbers in XML

Tags: xml, replace, find, notepad++

I use Notepad++ for basic XML Editing but I have an issue. I want to do something so that the following sequence is done automatically, instead of me using find and Replace multiple times.

21 becomes 22

22 becomes 24

23 becomes 26

24 becomes 28

25 becomes 30

26 becomes 32

27 becomes 34

28 becomes 36

29 becomes 38

30 becomes 40

31 becomes 42

32 becomes 44

33 becomes 46

34 becomes 48

.

Then
 35 becomes 50

36 becomes 51

37 becomes 52

38 becomes 53

All the way until

125 becomes 140

How will I be able to accomplish this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not a task for a text editor like Notepad++. You will need a scripting language (Python, Perl, etc) or something more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved declaratively, it needs to be solved programatically.
If you want to stay around Notepad++, you can reach for [JN plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jn-npp-plugin/) or [Python Script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).
These will allow you programmaticaly read and manipulate document content including adding values to numbers.